applying a transformation function on result of group by in python
import pandas as pd 
  
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Charlie', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40],
    'branch': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# concatenate the string 
df['branch'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['branch'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))    
  
# show the dataframe 
print(df) 

can anyone expain what's happening when we apply transformation function on result of group by?the output i am getting is



Name
Age
branch




Alice
25
New York Los Angeles


Alice
30
New York Los Angeles


Charlie
35
Chicago Houston


Charlie
40
Chicago Houston




The lambda function is called once for each partition, where you've already restricted the partition to just the branch series. So, in your case, x is an iterable containing two branches each time, and you join them together separated by a space. What specifically are you having trouble with, and what did you think the code would do?

@MatBailie firstly i don't understand why it is giving an entire iterable of two branches and not one. Secondly why the transform function is giving result two times(New York Los Angeles ,New York Los Angeles). I mean it should give one result for each iterable. Can you help me?

Check out the official Pandas documentation. GroupBy.transform : Call function producing a same-indexed Series on each group.
Returns a Series having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values.

You're NOT getting the output in your edit. Your code only updates the branch Series, and so the Age remains unchanged.

Open a new question with the same example data and show what you want the result to be.  It will evolve creating a new dataframe rather than modifying the existing one, and using apply rather than transform. (Do not edit the existing question to ask the new question.)

No. You are not meant to materially change the content of your question. Please open a NEW question in such cases.

The groupby function is applied on the df using the Name column as the grouping key. This means that the df is split into groups based on the unique values in the Name column.
What happens next in the applied transform function is that it applies the lambda function to each group independently.
The lambda function lambda x: ' '.join(x) is applied to each group of branch values. This function takes a group of branch values (represented by x) and joins them into a single string separated by spaces using the ' '.join(x) expression which returns a pd.Series that is finally assigned back to branch column.

why is count of each group is preserved. it should just give one value per group. Why it is giving 2 times joined values of branch? please help me

Because you are only taking care of branch in your transformation. While the difference in age for rows with same name is causing rows the duplicate branch

even if i take age values for each group same, it still duplicates the values returned from transformation function. while it should give one value per group. can you explain why?

Still because age is not taken care of. You can add it to your groupby and try again: df['branch'] = df.groupby(['Name', 'Age'])['branch'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))

i have editted the values of age in question. in df.groupby(['Name', 'Age']) now also transform function is returning 4 entries 2 for each group when it should return one entry per group. can you explain?
